# how to do statistic with time date

Tags: r, ggplot2

I got a serial of times, as following,

```
2013-12-27 00:31:15
2013-12-29 17:01:17
2013-12-31 01:52:41
....
```

my target is to know what time in a day is more important, like most times are in the period of 17:00 ~ 19:00.

In order to do that, I think I should draw every single time as a point in x-axes, and the unit of x-axes is minute.

1. I don't know how to do it exactly with R and `ggplot2`.
2. Am I on the right way? I mean, is there a better way to get my target?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
library(chron)

# create some test data - hrs

set.seed(123)

Lines <- "2013-12-27 00:31:15
2013-12-29 17:01:17
2013-12-31 01:52:41
"
tt0 <- times(read.table(text = Lines)[[2]]) %% 1
rng <- range(tt0)
hrs <- 24 * as.vector(sort(diff(rng) * runif(100)^2 + rng[1]))

# create density, find maximum of it and plot

d <- density(hrs)
max.hrs <- d$x[which.max(d$y)]
ggplot(data.frame(hrs)) + 
    geom_density(aes(hrs)) + 
    geom_vline(xintercept = max.hrs)
```

giving:

```
> max.hrs # in hours - nearly 2 am
[1] 1.989523 
> times(max.hrs / 24) # convert to times
[1] 01:59:22
```

[image]